# Set axes as variable value instead of variable index

Tags: python, matplotlib, kernel-density

I followed an example of kernel density estimation in 2-dimensions from https://kde-diffusion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html to calculate the density of random (x,y) data. The code are below:

```
from numpy.random import normal
x = normal(size=1000)
y = normal(size=1000)

# Estimate density within ±5 standard deviations.
from kde_diffusion import kde2d
(density, grid, bandwidth) = kde2d(x, y, n=32, limits=None)

# Display estimated density as image.
from matplotlib import pyplot
figure = pyplot.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot()
axes.imshow(density.T)
pyplot.show()
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzHHz.png)

Figure x,y axes are indexes of **grid**(array0(32 **x** variables), array1(32 **y** variables)). Is there any way to show x, y axes as corresponding variable value in array0 and array1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`density` here is a tuple with two elements, `x` and `y`. We can *unpack* the tuple as such: `x, y = density` and pack it up again as `x, y = density`